# Em::Blocks seems to treat my assembly input file as c file

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I'm using [Em::Blocks](http://www.emblocks.org/) for embedded development. My current project is including the assembly file [startup_stm32f429x.S](http://codepad.org/6TYC2lDR). Everything is compiling fine. However, when I'm replacing this file by the updated version [startup_stm32f429_439xx.s](http://codepad.org/3SGAeneM), then I get the following GCC errors when building:

```
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|1|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|2|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|3|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|4|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|5|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|6|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|7|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|8|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|9|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|10|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|11|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|12|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|13|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|14|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|15|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|16|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|17|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|18|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|19|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|21|Error: bad instruction `licensed under MCD-ST Liberty SW License Agreement V2,(the "License")'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|22|Error: bad instruction `you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|23|Error: bad instruction `you may obtain a copy of the License at:'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|27|Error: bad instruction `unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,software'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|28|Error: bad instruction `distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS"BASIS,'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|29|Error: bad instruction `without WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND,either express or implied.'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|30|Error: bad instruction `see the License for the specific language governing permissions and'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|31|Error: bad instruction `limitations under the License.'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|33|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|35|Error: bad instruction `amount of memory(in bytes)allocated for Stack'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|36|Error: bad instruction `tailor this value to your application needs'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|37|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `<'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|38|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `<'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|39|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `<'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|41|Error: bad instruction `stack_size EQU 0x00000400'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|43|Error: bad instruction `area STACK,NOINIT,READWRITE,ALIGN=3'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|44|Error: bad instruction `stack_mem SPACE Stack_Size'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|45|Error: bad instruction `__initial_sp'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|48|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `<'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|49|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `<'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|50|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `<'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|52|Error: bad instruction `heap_size EQU 0x00000200'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|54|Error: bad instruction `area HEAP,NOINIT,READWRITE,ALIGN=3'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|55|Error: bad instruction `__heap_base'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|56|Error: bad instruction `heap_mem SPACE Heap_Size'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|57|Error: bad instruction `__heap_limit'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|59|Error: bad instruction `preserve8'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|60|Error: bad instruction `thumb'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|63|Error: bad instruction `vector Table Mapped to Address 0 at Reset'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|64|Error: bad instruction `area RESET,DATA,READONLY'|
src\startup_stm32f429_439xx.s|65|Error: bad instruction `export __Vectors'|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build finished: 50 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 3 seconds) ===|
```

It seems to my, that Em::Blocks is somehow interpreting my file as C source file altough it is properly named. (.s-suffix stands for "Assembly source file which doesn't need to be preprocessed as far as I know.)

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? I didn't find any option to manually set the language of the file.

Comment: Note the difference in case of the filename extension... `.S` for the old file versus `.s` for the new. GCC treats files ending with lowercase `.s` as already preprocessed files so you can't have preprocessor macros or C-like comments in it.

Comment: Deleting the file from the project, changing the extension to `.S`, and re-adding it to the project sadly doesn't change anything.

Comment: Your "updated" file is using a different assembler syntax. It is probably intended for a different toolchain ("MDK-ARM").

Comment: I was using STM32Cube to configure the device and had the same problem. In my case the wrong assermbler file was added to the project.